# How to find distinct values from JSON file size more 100 gb

Tags: logging, jq

I am streaming a decompressed 100GB JSON log file from a remote location. The goal is to find the distinct values in a file

**Input format**

```
{
  {
    "requestID": "1234",
    "caller": "bob"
  },

  {
    "requestID": "1235",
    "caller": "cat"
  },

  {
    "requestID": "1236",
    "caller": "bob"
  }
}
```

**Expect output**

```
bob
cat
```

I have tried JQ, awk but given file is big is cannot be sorted or slurpped.

Comment: If you are looking for a unique value, why do you expect two?  what makes you think you might have to slurp or sort the file? … ???

Comment: Are you perhaps trying to ascertain all the *distinct* values of .caller ?

Comment: Also, the snippet you show is not valid JSON or JSONLines. Please clarify what exactly the input looks like.

Comment: To obtain all the distinct values of .caller efficiently, first ensure the input consists of a stream of the .caller objects; then using `jq -nr 'INDEX(inputs|.caller;.)|keys_unsorted[]'`.  This avoids the need for any sorting or slurping, and should be very fast and reasonably memory-efficient. If a solution that tilts towards using less memory is needed, then you'd use `foreach`.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: Don't parse JSON with tools that do not understand JSON. Use JSON tools when available.

---

If your file is always formatted as shown (each caller on its own line; no line breaks in the caller name; no other properties on the caller line), `awk` + `cut` might do the job though:

```
$ < input.json awk '/"caller":/ && !seen[$0]++' | cut -d'"' -f4
```

Or perhaps:

```
$ < input.json grep '"caller":' | cut -d'"' -f4 | awk '!seen[$0]++'
```